# Why doesn't polars reuse the already evaluated results of repeated expressions within one context?

Tags: optimization, python-polars

[This Polars User Guide page](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/lazy/optimizations/) says

> Common subplan elimination - Cache subtrees/file scans that are used by multiple subtrees in the query plan.

I don't know what does a subtree mean in this context, but I was hoping that Polars would try to reuse the result of a subexpression evaluation if it was used multiple times within one context. But the example below shows that it's not true.

```py
# polars==0.18.3

import polars as pl
import time
import os


def compute_heavily(initial_value: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    """Waste some CPU power to compute the golden ratio"""
    result = initial_value
    for i in range(100):
        result = (1 + result) ** 0.5
    return result


# Block parallel execution of polars expressions
os.environ["POLARS_MAX_THREADS"] = "1"
# Create a dataframe
df = pl.DataFrame(pl.repeat(0.0, 10_000_000, eager=True).alias("value"))

# Case A
start_time = time.perf_counter()
df_a = (
    df.lazy().with_columns(compute_heavily(pl.col("value")).alias("result_1")).collect()
)
delta_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
print(f"Case A: function called once: {delta_time:.3f} s.")

# Case B
start_time = time.perf_counter()
df_b = (
    df.lazy()
    .with_columns(compute_heavily(pl.col("value")).alias("result_1"))
    .with_columns((pl.col("result_1")).alias("result_2"))
    .collect()
)
delta_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
print(
    f"Case B: function called once in one context "
    f"and the result is used in an updated context: {delta_time:.3f} s."
)

# Case C
start_time = time.perf_counter()
df_c = (
    df.lazy()
    .with_columns(compute_heavily(pl.col("value")).alias("result_1"))
    .with_columns(compute_heavily(pl.col("value")).alias("result_2"))
    .collect()
)
delta_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
print(
    f"Case C: function called twice, "
    f"but each time in a different context: {delta_time:.3f} s."
)

# Case D
start_time = time.perf_counter()
df_d = (
    df.lazy()
    .with_columns(
        (compute_heavily(pl.col("value")) + compute_heavily(pl.col("value"))).alias(
            "result_1"
        )
    )
    .collect()
)
delta_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
print(
    f"Case D: function called twice within one context "
    f"to make one column: {delta_time:.3f} s."
)

# Case E
start_time = time.perf_counter()
df_e = (
    df.lazy()
    .with_columns(
        [
            compute_heavily(pl.col("value").alias("result_1")),
            compute_heavily(pl.col("value")).alias("result_2"),
        ]
    )
    .collect()
)
delta_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
print(
    f"Case E: function called twice within one context, "
    f"but each time for a different column: {delta_time:.3f} s."
)
```

```
Case A: function called once: 2.124 s.
Case B: function called once in one context and the result is used in an updated context: 2.208 s.
Case C: function called twice, but each time in a different context: 4.454 s.
Case D: function called twice within one context to make one column: 4.390 s.
Case E: function called twice within one context, but each time for a different column: 4.299 s.
```

Cases A, B and C work as I expected: A and B take 1 time unit (as the function is explicitly called once), and C takes 2 time units (as the function is explicitly called twice within different contexts). Cases D and E take 2 time units, but I thought they would take only 1 thanks to optimization.

1. Is this how Polars is meant to work?
2. What does a `Common subplan elimination` mean?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something here, but you're executing an "external" python function which runs before polars does anything, is not equivalent to: `a = compute_heavily(); b = compute_heavily(); df.with_columns(result_1 = a, result_2 = b)`?

Comment: `compute_heavily()` doesn't compute anything. It's actually an expression builder - it takes in a `pl.Expr` and outputs another `pl.Expr`. All the computation happens during `.collect()` for a lazy dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There now exists, as @ritchie46 alluded to, Common Sub Expressions which does exactly what OP is asking about. For example if we do:

```
(
    df.lazy()
    .with_columns(
        (compute_heavily(pl.col("value")) + compute_heavily(pl.col("value"))).alias(
            "result_1"
        )
    )
    .explain()
)
# WITH_COLUMNS:
#  [[(col("__POLARS_CSER_3495242331465746361")) + (col("__POLARS_CSER_3495242331465746361"))].alias("result_1"), [(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + ([(1.0) + (col("value"))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]))].pow([0.5]).alias("__POLARS_CSER_3495242331465746361")]
#   DF ["value"]; PROJECT */1 COLUMNS; SELECTION: "None"
```

You can see reference to `col("__POLARS_CSER_3495242331465746361")`, that's the cached value of the calc which it only does once.

I'm on version 0.19.11.

Answer (score 2):

`common_subplan_elimination` removes common subplans on a query level (e.g. joins, sorts, read_files`, but not on an expression level.

This is something we still need to implement. There is currently an expression that sets this manually:

```py
# manually cache the result node
a = compute_heavily(pl.col("value")).cache()

df_d = (
    df.with_columns(
        (a + a).alias(
            "result_1"
        )
    )
)
```

Though we advice not to use it in most cases. It increases contention a lot. We will first need to change the way we evaluate expressions, once we have cached nodes.